# Semantic UI React Sidebar OnHide

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, sidebar, semantic-ui-react

I am working with a full page sidebar in Semantic UI React with the Dimmer added.  It is working great on all devices except Safari and iOS (iPad/iPhone) etc.  The issue I am running into is that the click event that normally triggers the "onHide" function to be called doesn't seem like it is working on apple devices.  If you navigate to Semantic React's documentation for a dimmed sidebar it occurs with the example as well:

http://react.semantic-ui.com/maximize/sidebar-example-dimmed/

and a link to their sidebar documentation:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/

Steps to produce:

1. Toggle the dimmed sidebar to show on your computer/desktop (or any other browser besides Safari it seems like).
2. On your computer click anywhere inside the dimmed area - the sidebar toggles and hides.
3. Do this on an iPad/iPhone (Safari) - the onhide event is never triggered by clicking the dimmed area.

Am I missing something here in Semantic UI React?  Is there an easy way to get the onhide trigger to fire when clicking into the dimmed area for a full page sidebar on apple devices (I have no toggle button on my site)?

[image]

**EDIT**:  This appears to be specific to iPhone and iPad and not Safari.

Comment: I checked this on Safari and it works fine. Do you mean just on iPhone/iPad?

Comment: @LazarNikolic - yes, it appears to be just iPhone and iPad.  I did test it with Chrome on an iPad and you're correct, it seemed to not work on that either.